# Identifying Hidden Elements in PDF from Chrome Page Breaks

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf document created by Google Chrome. When parsing the text via PDFBox (Java), I found that there was a hidden block of text straddled between the pages. Although the rendering mode was "FILL", I found that the element was off the page. Problem solved.

Now, I find that another similar element also appears off the page, but the coordinates to not tell this. It is within the visible margin of the second page that it straddles. It has y2 = 31.195312 and max height of 29.894833 (Font size = 36). Calculated y1 is about 1, still on the page.

The text positions obj shows some interesting internal properties, but they are not public vars. All I have is this TextPosition object (https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html) and the surrounding context.

I can reproduce the issue, but it requires my particular document. Could be attempted with page-break-inside tests, but I haven't found a simple test for it. I'm looking for some kind of margin, but so far all the boxes from within this.getCurrentPage() show just the plain page height, and no start position. Another possibility is that there is another way of looking for the coordinates than firstTextPos.getY() and firstTextPos.getHeight().

PDF in Mac Preview:

[image]

The text is selected between pages and is listed on the second page. In the case where it is listed on the first page, I am able to handle the issue as described above.

TextPosition object **private** vars:

[image]

Comment: if (y1 < 5), ie. when y1 = 1 handles the situation sofar, but that provides no explanation and could be incomplete.

Comment: Not also, text in the blank is repeated from the text in the page, can be copy-pasted.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question so that it has all your thoughts. You should also write a question into your question, it is not clear what you're asking. If you want to find for elements that go outside the page media box, say so. Btw there is no such thing as stuff "between pages". It always belongs to one specific page.

Comment: Exactly as @Tilman comments... What is the question here? Chances are, though, that whatever the question may be, a sample PDF is needed.